# How do these "Notification Manager" app work in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I am building an interruption filter app for android (for my college project) and would like to disable Heads-up Notifications from other app popping up. However, I couldn't find any resources about achieving this function. However, these notification manager applications below in play store does block Heads-up Notifications from some application, which is kind of the function I wish to build. I am wondering how do they actually block Heads-up Notifications?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.android.notifications&hl=en_GB
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmsecurity.notimanager&hl=en_GB

Any answer to the questions or solution for blocking Heads-up notification are welcomed and much appreciated. Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this extending a [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html), with this service you recieve calls from the system whenever a new notification arrives and you also can cancel any notification.

However this service is only available for API 18 onward.